Apollo Client lazy query doesn't work after router.push
I use Apollo Client lazy query to make a call for a number of organizations that appear in my project. Because of their numerous amount I've created an infinite scroll functionality that uses this very lazy query:
  //query for all the organizations
  console.log('first');
  const { data: allOrganizations } = await getStudioOrganizations({
    variables: {
      take: 10,
      orderBy: {
        createdAt: 'asc',
      },
      skip: 0,
      where2: {
        NOT: [
          {
            title: {
              equals:
                firstOrganization?.production.project?.organization.title,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
  console.log('second');

It works pretty well and I can do whatever I want with that "data" variable inside this block of code.
But after I use router.push (or replace, whatsoever) to change my url (my layout component is one for all the url paths) and the page is rendered anew - this query stops working. The code after the query is not executed and istead "first second" I get just "first" in console - and the query's loader spins forever and doesn't change it's boolean value.
I've tried to get rid of these "data" variables destructurized of the awaited query in this function and to use the same variables in the global state where I declare my lazy query. It makes it possible to access new data after doing router.push but it's not solving the problem because of the structure of my code - I simply have to destructurize query data this way.
There is also nothing in Apollo devtools after I run router.push. 21 queries goes to 0 after route changing.
I guess there's some underhood stuff going on with those Apollo queries or they are just stuck in the old unmounted scope? Or they simple doesn't work with react router?
I'll be glad to recieve a couple of ideas on that matter.
